# ATmega328p - ISC00 with INT1?

Tags: interrupt, atmega328, avr

I was reading about external interrupts using the ATmega328p, and I saw in the chip datasheet under the paragraph "Bits 3:2 – ISC1n: Interrupt Sense Control 1 [n = 1:0]" the following table:

```
Value | Description 
------+------------------------------------------------------------
00    | The low level of INT1 generates an interrupt request.
01    | Any logical change on INT1 generates an interrupt request.
10    | The falling edge of INT1 generates an interrupt request.
11    | The rising edge of INT1 generates an interrupt request.
```

From what I understand from the table title and the definition in the datasheet that ISC1n where n=1|0, is dedicated for INT1. And that ISC0n where n=1|0, is dedicated for INT0. However, in the table above, the value 00 is described as "The low level of INT1 generates an interrupt request.".

What I don't understand is how can ISC0n where n=1|0 be dedicated for INT0 but in the table above the value 00 (or ISC00) is used for INT1 ? I could totally be missing something but I would appreciate any guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understand from the table title and the definition in the
>   datasheet that ISC1n where n=1|0, is dedicated for INT1. And that
>   ISC0n where n=1|0, is dedicated for INT0.

This is correct.

> [...] in the table above the value 00 (or ISC00) is used for INT1

This is your misunderstanding. The value "00" in the table does not mean
ISC00. The "Value" column of the table is the value you get by
concatenating the bits ISC11 and ISC10. Thus:

- "Value = 00" means ISC11 = 0 and ISC10 = 0
- "Value = 01" means ISC11 = 0 and ISC10 = 1
- "Value = 10" means ISC11 = 1 and ISC10 = 0
- "Value = 11" means ISC11 = 1 and ISC10 = 1

Comment: Ohh I understand it now! Edgar that's an amazing explanation! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo. My revision of the datasheet (revision G) properly says "INT0".

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!!! Where can I find the newest version of the PDF, Google seems to index the one with the typo first ?

Comment: The latest revision of any Atmel datasheet is available from Atmel's website. I have confirmed that revision B of the 328/328P datasheet does not have that typo.

Comment: Cool I'll check on their website. Thank again!

Comment: I think this is it: [ATmega48A/PA/88A/PA/168A
/PA/328/P DATASHEET](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) - revision J.

Comment: Atmel split the 328/P parts into a separate datasheet recently (for a certain definition of "recently").

Comment: Revision B of the Complete datasheet of the ATmega328p has the same type, but some more recent PDFs like the one posted by @NickGammon does not. Thank Nick for the link!

Comment: Atmel-42735B-ATmega328/P_Datasheet_Complete-11/2016? I'm not seeing the typo there, unless I'm looking in completely the wrong place.

Comment: In the PDF at http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf, page 89 (Both tables)

Comment: I'm seeing "INT0" in the table on that page, under "Bits 1:0 – ISC0n".

Comment: Correct, but in "Bits 1:0 – ISC0n" table they also put "Value: 10, Description:
The falling edge of INT0 generates an interrupt request" that what confused me

Comment: I'm not seeing what's wrong with that. ISC0n is about INT0, and 0b10 means an interrupt on a trailing edge.

Comment: From what I understand from this PDF: ISC00, ISC01, ISC10 and ISC11 can be for both INT0 and INT1. However, the newer PDF mention: ISC00 and ISC01 is for INT0. And ISC10 and ISC11 are for INT1

Comment: The register descriptions *explicitly* state that ISC1n is for INT1 and ISC0n is for INT0 in the first two sentences of the first paragraph of each.

Comment: Yup, you're right, just the tables contradicted those statements. But it's good I know it's fixed in the newer revision. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again guys for the help, Edgar in his answer saw where my mistake is.